# How to use a custom parser with Python's Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am using [Beautiful Soup 4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to parse and modify a set of HTML files. The HTML files are Angular templates, which means their markup is somehow different than the one in regular HTML documents (mixed case attributes, directives, input/output bindings, etc.).

None of the parsers listed in Beautiful Soups [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) (html.parser, lxml, html5lib) totally fit my needs. The closest to it is Python’s built in html.parser, but I had to make a few adjustments to it.

Is it possible to use a custom parser class with Beautiful Soup? If yes, how could this be implemented?

**Edit:** Below is an example of how Beautiful Soup parses a template. The main issue is that all attributes from the result are lowercase (*ngIf -> *ngif) and the directives (appAutoFocus, appKeepFocusInside, etc.) get an empty string value (e.g. appautofocus="").

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

test_html = """
<kendo-dialog *ngIf="dialogOpened" appAutoFocus appKeepFocusInside (close)="closeDialog()" width="1000">
   <kendo-dialog-titlebar>A title</kendo-dialog-titlebar>
   <div *ngIf="model.showValidationFailedMessage" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
      <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="model.closeValidationAlert()"><span
         aria-hidden="true">&amp;times;</span></button>
      Validation failed
   </div>

   <kendo-tabstrip [keepTabContent]="true">
      <kendo-tabstrip-tab title="Tab title 1" [selected]="true">
         <ng-template kendoTabContent>
            <div>Tab content</div>
         </ng-template>
      </kendo-tabstrip-tab>
   </kendo-tabstrip>
</kendo-dialog>
"""

document = BeautifulSoup(test_html, "html.parser")
print(document.prettify())
```

Result:

```
<kendo-dialog (close)="closeDialog()" *ngif="dialogOpened" appautofocus="" appkeepfocusinside="" width="1000">
 <kendo-dialog-titlebar>
  A title
 </kendo-dialog-titlebar>
 <div *ngif="model.showValidationFailedMessage" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
  <button (click)="model.closeValidationAlert()" aria-label="Close" class="close" type="button">
   <span aria-hidden="true">
    &amp;times;
   </span>
  </button>
  Validation failed
 </div>
 <kendo-tabstrip [keeptabcontent]="true">
  <kendo-tabstrip-tab [selected]="true" title="Tab title 1">
   <ng-template kendotabcontent="">
    <div>
     Tab content
    </div>
   </ng-template>
  </kendo-tabstrip-tab>
 </kendo-tabstrip>
</kendo-dialog>
```

Comment: did you try to use BS with angular ? Did you get problem ? Show it on example.

Comment: @furas I added an example to my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`bs4.builder.register_treebuilders_from`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/449/bs4/builder/__init__.py#L300). The built-in builders are the modules in [`bs4.builder`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/files/449/bs4/builder) package. For example, [`bs4.builder._lxml`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/449/bs4/builder/_lxml.py).

Here's `register_treebuilders_from`.

```
def register_treebuilders_from(module):
    """Copy TreeBuilders from the given module into this module."""
    # I'm fairly sure this is not the best way to do this.
    this_module = sys.modules['bs4.builder']
    for name in module.__all__:
        obj = getattr(module, name)

        if issubclass(obj, TreeBuilder):
            setattr(this_module, name, obj)
            this_module.__all__.append(name)
            # Register the builder while we're at it.
            this_module.builder_registry.register(obj)
```

And tail of the package's root module.

```
# Builders are registered in reverse order of priority, so that custom
# builder registrations will take precedence. In general, we want lxml
# to take precedence over html5lib, because it's faster. And we only
# want to use HTMLParser as a last result.
from . import _htmlparser
register_treebuilders_from(_htmlparser)
try:
    from . import _html5lib
    register_treebuilders_from(_html5lib)
except ImportError:
    # They don't have html5lib installed.
    pass
try:
    from . import _lxml
    register_treebuilders_from(_lxml)
except ImportError:
    # They don't have lxml installed.
    pass
```

Thus, you're expected to create a module with a subclass of `bs4.builder.TreeBuilder` and register it in `__all__` of the module. Then pass the module to `register_treebuilders_from`.